# What is a good Bazaar cheat sheet for the most common tasks?

Tags: application-development, launchpad, bazaar, version-control

Plenty of documentation out there, but it seems to be either an introduction tutorial (aka not a cheat sheet), or a technical cheat sheet with too many commands (aka the manpage).

Is there a good cheat sheet that either just covers the most common, or one that is well categorized so the task you want to do can be easily found?

Comment: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Bazaar

Comment: If you want a nice GUI, try Bazaar Explorer (`sudo apt-get install bzr-explorer`). It's one of the best GUIs for a VCS I've used. It also shows exactly which commands it executes so you'll learn them too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer [this](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/en/) page.

- [Version 2.6](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.6/en/quick-reference/index.html)
- [Version 2.7](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.dev/en/quick-reference/index.html)

---

[image]